# UnauthorizedAccessException in LINQPad

Tags: c#, linqpad

```
    public void LoadVectors(string model_file)
{
    var file = model_file;
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(file, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        wordCount = br.ReadInt32();
        Dimensions = br.ReadInt32();
        for (var w = 0; w < wordCount; w++)
        {
            var word = br.ReadString();
            var vec = new float[Dimensions];
            for (var d = 0; d < Dimensions; d++) vec[d] = br.ReadSingle();
            Normalise(vec);
            model[word] = vec;
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this function in this function

```
private static void Train()
{
    // Train vector model and save to file.
    var word2vec = new Word2Vec();
    word2vec.Train("corpus.txt", "model.bin");
}
```

where `corpus.txt` is something that I already trained and doesn't matter in this question, and `model.bin` is something that I need to read.

But when I call this, it gives me an `UnauthorizedAccessException` at 
`'C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad5\model.bin'` and this is not the right location for `model.bin`

When I try to put the absolute location of `model.bin` by doing

```
word2vec.Train("corpus.txt", @"D:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\word2VecTest\word2VecTest\bin\Debug\model.bin");
```

It gives me the same error.

How can I set this location to work in LINQPad??

Comment: Your examples don't make sense. Your first function is called LoadVectors and takes one parameter , yet you are calling a function called Train which takes two parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run your program as admin. this could be your solution.